# How to get width of text pushed by an image?

Tags: javascript, width

Sometimes sites will set up their articles in such a way that the image associated will be placed not above the article text, but in the top left with the text along the right side.

[image: Example Article with text pushed]

In the above screenshot, an image is placed into the article but the `<p>` tag still has a width that equals the length of the parent div. 
I want to be able to calculate when the first `<p>` has text that is not squished due to the added image.

I've tried various methods to calculate the `width` including `.offsetWidth`, `.getBoundingClientRect().width` and each time it returns the same **560** value

I'm not sure what other ways I can search this on SO or Google.
I should also note I do not have control over the actual content that is on the page. I'm just working on the content dynamically after the page loads.

I added a snippet of how it is setup on this page (again I don't have control over the source).

```css
.lead-img {text-align: center;}

 img.alignleft{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 25px 5px 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="lead-img">
      <img class="alignleft " style="background-color:lightgreen;height:250px;width:250px;">
     </div>
    <div>
      <span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p>
      <p> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex</p>
      <p>ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could add the markup and the CSS to reproduce the layout and the issue. There's more than one way to build the same layout.

Comment: I added a snippet of what it looks like on the page. Again, I know there are multiple ways to make a page look like this, but I don't have control over that. I just have to work with what's given to me and just need to figure out those width values.

Comment: Yes, I can understand, that you've a "read-only" page. Interestingly if you'll select a p element for inspecting, and then hover over the text node in it (in the markup window), you can see the correct width. How does browser calculate that, is not known, yet ...

Comment: You can use setInterval() function to call the calculate width function recursively

Comment: @Teemu That's not what I'm seeing for the test setup :(

Comment: No? I can see the width of the actual text node in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Your function will be called only once after the page loads, you need to add something to have the function called in a time interval or a listener to look up for changes in the page, I tried using setInterval function in this sample: https://jsfiddle.net/qz2hdbvm/